# How to run a PHP project on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I started learning Php and we have a php project (framework Codeigniter) running on Server. I want to run it locally and understand more the code how it works.

I installed WAMP server and copied the source code file under 'www'. I have created a database with the same name on phpmyadmin and imported the tables from .sql file.
I have changed the database.php to run locally

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'report';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Then when I put on browser localhost/report,
I receive many errors like this

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: c
>
> Filename: views/pool.php
>
> Line Number: 13
>
> Request method: GET
>
> Request uri: /report/

Many variables are not defined in the views. Should i change something other yet so that the views will be working ? I am new to Php and i have been following many tutorials but i still can't make it work.

Another question please, do i need to install code Igniter too ? or enough wamp and the source code. 
Any suggestions please ? Thank you.

Comment: can you show pool.php

Comment: I would start with the latest version of codeigniter if your new https://www.codeigniter.com/

Comment: Sounds to me like that is really old legacy code, written for a much older php version or with error visualization explicitly turned off, whilst you are running a current php version with enabled error visualization.

Comment: Check your view pool.php.Or might problem with php version.

Comment: Thanks. One question please, do i need to install code Igniter too ? or enough wamp and the source code

Answer (score 0):

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: c

Filename: views/pool.php

Line Number: 13

Request method: GET

Request uri: /report/

This error is showing that variable "c" is not defined on line number 13 in views/pool.php, what else you wanted to know, just check that or you can turn the error reporting off to hide all these errors in index.php file in your projects root folder.   just change the ENVIRONMENT constant "production" or "testing"

Comment: Thanks. One question please, do i need to install code Igniter too ? or enough wamp and the source code

Comment: There's nothing to install in CodeIgniter, its just your folder structures, if your folder stucture is like this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/images/directory_structure.jpg
then its all good. I strongly recommend you to take a look here https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly in file `views/pool.php`, line number 13. That is what you should provide so that we can check what might be wrong.

You are using CodeIgniter, an MVC framework and the error is in one of your views. Bear in mind that views are templates. That means:

- You have to mark your variables somehow, to let the template engine know
  that you want to output data from your application --same applies for control structures like `if`/`else`, `for`, etc.- In the case of CodeIgniter, it is done with PHP-style codes `<? ?>`.
- You have to tell your application which data the view will have access to.
  If you don't pass that data to the view, it will fail even if you used the
  correct syntax. You have to do this in your controller function:

  `$mydata = ['c' => 'cool!', 'user_id' => 123, ...];
  $this->load->view('pool', $mydata);`

Go to [CodeIgniter's views documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) and you will find a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks. One question please, do i need to install code Igniter too ? or enough wamp and the source code

Comment: Yes, you have to install CodeIgniter. Don't you already have it installed? Go to the user guide (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation); it's really easy.